# Android application download on SD card

Tags: android

Can Android application request to download on SD card in android 2.1 and lower.
Also I want to know if the application can request some folders that contain videos to download on the sd card ? and how to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the external storage information in the Google documentation. It provides some good code examples and descriptions.

http://d.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal